# Iterate over parent elements based on values of child elements

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

This seems like a really simple thing but I haven't figured out how to do it. Given XML snippet:

```
<programs>
  <program>
    <title>Program 1</title>
    <time>2011-01-05 12:00:00</time>
    <code>a</code>
  </program>
  <program>
    <title>Program 2</title>
    <time>2011-01-05 12:30:00</time>
    <code>b</code>
  </program>
  <program>
    <title>Program 1</title>
    <time>2011-01-06 12:00:00</time>
    <code>a</code>
  </program>
</programs>
```

How do I iterate over  where  starts with '2011-01-05' and *code* equals *a*? I know how to do this for one element and I have seemingly written code that will do either/or but I can't hit on the right syntax for *AND* logic.

if the variable *data* contains my XML then I can use `$(data).find("code:contentIs('a'),time:contains('2011-01-05')").parent()` to get both *Program 1* and *Program 2* but I only want to get *Program 1*.

*(contentIs is a function I wrote that I know works so don't pay attention to that)*

I tried `$(data).find("code:contentIs('a'):time:contains('2011-01-05')").parent()` but I get **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: time**

I feel like I've gotta be missing some basic syntax here but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector) here. It finds elements that have descendant elements that match a selector.

```
$(data).find('program:has(code:contentIs("a")):has(time:contains("2011-01-05"))');
```

Using the `has` selector twice says "ensure the element matches both requirements". This is the same as selecting by two classes, e.g. `a.someClass.someOtherClass`.

Comment: Excellent, that was precisely what I needed. Thanks again.